# Call to undefined function password_hash()

Tags: php, password-hash

Пытаюсь шифровать пароли, вводимые при регистрации, с помощью функции `password_hash()`. Но получаю ошибку:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function password_hash()

Не могу понять причины. PHP у меня на хостинге версии 7.0.3. Никаких упоминаний о том, что эта функция не работает в данной версии я не нашла.

В чем может быть проблема, подскажите, пожалуйста. И как исправить?
Спасибо!

Код такой:

```
if(isset($_POST['pass'])) {$prepass = $_POST['pass'];};
if(isset($_POST['repass'])) {$prerepass = $_POST['repass'];};

$pass1=serialize($prepass);
$repass1=serialize($prerepass);

$pass = password_hash($pass1);
$repass = password_hash($repass1);
```

P.S. Уточнила у хостера версию php:  - версия 7.3.13 (alt)

Comment: Вы уверены что версия php 7.0.3 ??

Comment: Уточнила у хостера: версия 7.3.13 (alt)

Comment: @Наталья лучше не уточняйте, а добавьте в файл `echo phpversion();` На всех версиях свыше 5.5 всё работает корректно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `password_hash` требует как минимум 2 параметра - само значение и тип шифорвания - параметр `algo` подробнее [Тут](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/password.constants.php)

Пример:

```php
<?php
if(isset($_POST['pass'])) {$prepass = $_POST['pass'];};
if(isset($_POST['repass'])) {$prerepass = $_POST['repass'];};

$pass1=serialize($prepass);
$repass1=serialize($prerepass);

$pass = password_hash($pass1, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$repass = password_hash($repass1, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

print_r($pass);
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input id="pass" name="pass">
<input id="repass" name="repass">
    <button formmethod="post">Send</button>
</form>
```

Код
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат выполнения при введённых данных
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я пробовала параметры: PASSWORD_DEFAULT и Вами предложенный PASSWORD_BCRYPT - результат нулевой. То есть тот же самый, что и указан в вопросе: Call to undefined function password_hash()

Comment: @Наталья всё работает корректно. Добавил скрины кода и результат его выполнения. Сравните полностью свой код.

Comment: Ой, а я без algo: писала. Просто через запятую, как в мануале. Пропала ошибка. Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Наталья Такое случается, не переживайте ) Главное всё получилось )

Answer (score 0):

Судя по `Call to undefined function`, можно сделать вывод что идет вызов не объявленной функции.

Cоздайте тестовый файл и вызовите в нём `phpinfo()`. В самом начале будет написана текущая версия, не может быть что в 7 версии пишет подобную ошибку.